# sidebar is stuck under the content

Tags: html, css

I tried to create responsive menu which after resizing (<992px) create hamburger menu that will roll from the right side and it will be on 100vh of website's height. Everything works but the content of the website is on top of the sidebar menu after transition. I tried to set the position to absolute or relative nothing works. Also I tried to hide the content after label is checked but it didn't work too. Any ideas how can I fix that?

**Code:**

```css
/* General */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 0.9375rem;
  padding-right: 0.9375rem;
}

.main-content {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: linear-gradient(70deg, #0ebeff, #ffdd40, #ae63e4, #47cf73);
}


/* Menu */

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 58px;
}

.menu-items ul {
  float: right;
}

.menu-items ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-items ul li a {
  line-height: 75px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-items ul li a:hover {
  color: #4956cc;
  transition: 0.1s
}

.menu-items ul li a.active {
  color: #ffa136;
}

.logo-place {
  line-height: 75px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

.checkbtn {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000;
  float: right;
  line-height: 85px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
  .checkbtn {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-items ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 80px;
    right: -100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
  }
  .menu-items ul li {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .menu-items ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  #check:checked~.menu-items ul {
    right: 0;
  }
}


/* Welcome-section */

.welcome-section {
  background-color: red;
}

.welcome-section h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="menu container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
    <div class="logo-place">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-items">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">My Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank">Linkedin</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="welcome-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="portrait">
          <img src="img/portrait.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <h1>bla bla bla bla bla <br> bla bla bla.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

Comment: You can hide content with css visibility or you can use JS and remove it.

Comment: @user13806962 there is a [far simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64268427/12860895) way to solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the sidebar a `z-index`:

```
.menu-items ul {
  float: right;
  z-index: 999; /* Insert this line */
}
```

> The `z-index` CSS property sets the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants or flex items. Overlapping elements with a larger z-index cover those with a smaller one.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

```css
/* General */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 0.9375rem;
  padding-right: 0.9375rem;
}

.main-content {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background: linear-gradient(70deg, #0ebeff, #ffdd40, #ae63e4, #47cf73);
}


/* Menu */

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 58px;
}

.menu-items ul {
  float: right;
  z-index: 999;
}

.menu-items ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu-items ul li a {
  line-height: 75px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-items ul li a:hover {
  color: #4956cc;
  transition: 0.1s
}

.menu-items ul li a.active {
  color: #ffa136;
}

.logo-place {
  line-height: 75px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

.checkbtn {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000;
  float: right;
  line-height: 85px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
  .checkbtn {
    display: block;
  }

  .menu-items ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 80px;
    right: -100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
  }

  .menu-items ul li {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .menu-items ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
  }

  #check:checked~.menu-items ul {
    right: 0;
  }
}


/* Welcome-section */

.welcome-section {
  background-color: red;
}

.welcome-section h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="menu container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </label>
    <div class="logo-place">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-items">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">My Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank">Linkedin</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="welcome-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="portrait">
          <img src="img/portrait.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <h1>bla bla bla bla bla <br> bla bla bla.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Yes, it works but after I scroll some content will reveal.

Comment: @Aryan_Beezadhur - You didn't explain *what* z-index is, and I think it'd be useful to do that.   After all it helps to explain why a solution works! So I'm going to give a brief explanation. Z-index specifics the stack order of an element, that is to say, if it's on top of other elements or below them. The higher a z-index is, the closer to the top of the stack it'll be, whereas the lower it is, the closer it'll be to the bottom of the stack. Check out the docs for more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: @marsnebulasoup I've added an explanation

Comment: Great! I think your answer now makes more sense to someone who didn't already know why the solution worked.

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur But after the sidebar show and side has more content then header after scroll will go up and reveal a little bit of website on the top how can I prevent from leaving the space on top where should be header. I set the position of menu on fixed and also z index but it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Add `z-index: 9;` to `.menu-items ul` which is in `@media (max-width:992px)`